# How can I sort an array of data by given value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs3

How can I create a function that will sort an array of data depending on the value of a given field? Suppose the field has three numbers: 1,2,3.
And depending on what value I send to the function, it will sort the table according to that value.
Example Array(console.log output):

```
0: {id: '1', nazwa: 'Example', lokalizacja: 'Example', klucz: 'Example', edit: '0'}
1: {id: '2', nazwa: 'Example', lokalizacja: 'Example', klucz: 'Example', edit: '0'}
2: {id: '2', nazwa: 'Example', lokalizacja: 'Example', klucz: 'Example', edit: '0'}
3: {id: '3', nazwa: 'Example', lokalizacja: 'Example', klucz: 'Example', edit: '0'}
```

For example, here I would like to sort an array by an `id` of two and get sorted output like that:

```
    0: {id: '2', nazwa: 'Example', lokalizacja: 'Example', klucz: 'Example', edit: '0'}
    1: {id: '2', nazwa: 'Example', lokalizacja: 'Example', klucz: 'Example', edit: '0'}
    2: {id: '1', nazwa: 'Example', lokalizacja: 'Example', klucz: 'Example', edit: '0'}
    3: {id: '3', nazwa: 'Example', lokalizacja: 'Example', klucz: 'Example', edit: '0'}
```

How can I achieve this or how can I get started?

Comment: Please show expected output for given input.

Comment: What would be the result of "sort by 2"? Usually you sort by a property/attribute/column, using the values found there, not a specific value

Comment: Your code is not an array. Maybe just me but I just see four objects. Can you share how the array is supposed to be structured?

Comment: I have no clue what it means when you say "sort an array by an id of two"

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I edited question. Please look what I want to get.

Comment: @Sarah It's console.log output

Comment: @epascarello I edited question and I showed what output I want

Comment: also [Lodash sortby first condition and then check for other conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70704085/lodash-sortby-first-condition-and-then-check-for-other-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that you want to get specific values first and then in whatever order.

```js
const data = [{
  id: '1',
  nazwa: 'Example',
  lokalizacja: 'Example',
  klucz: 'Example',
  edit: '0'
}, {
  id: '2',
  nazwa: 'Example',
  lokalizacja: 'Example',
  klucz: 'Example',
  edit: '0'
}, {
  id: '2',
  nazwa: 'Example',
  lokalizacja: 'Example',
  klucz: 'Example',
  edit: '0'
}, {
  id: '3',
  nazwa: 'Example',
  lokalizacja: 'Example',
  klucz: 'Example',
  edit: '0'
}]

const sorted = sortByKeyAndValue(data, 'id', '2')

console.log(sorted)

function sortByKeyAndValue(data, key, value) {
  return [...data].sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[key] === value) return -1
    if (b[key] === value) return 1
    return a[key].localeCompare(b[key])
  })
}
```

I used `[...data]` instead of `data` because `Array.prorotype.sort` modifies the array in place instead of creating a new one.

Version without creating a new array.

```js
const data = [{
  id: '1',
  nazwa: 'Example',
  lokalizacja: 'Example',
  klucz: 'Example',
  edit: '0'
}, {
  id: '2',
  nazwa: 'Example',
  lokalizacja: 'Example',
  klucz: 'Example',
  edit: '0'
}, {
  id: '2',
  nazwa: 'Example',
  lokalizacja: 'Example',
  klucz: 'Example',
  edit: '0'
}, {
  id: '3',
  nazwa: 'Example',
  lokalizacja: 'Example',
  klucz: 'Example',
  edit: '0'
}]

sortByKeyAndValue(data, 'id', '2')

console.log(data)

function sortByKeyAndValue(data, key, value) {
  data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[key] === value) return -1
    if (b[key] === value) return 1
    return a[key].localeCompare(b[key])
  })
}
```

Comment: _"What I understood..."_ - is just another _"how to sort for depending on multiple properties"_ question which has already been asked multiple times on SO and therefor is just another duplicate... - So why the answer instead of a close-vote as obvious dupe?

Comment: Why `[...data]` when `data` is already an array?

Comment: I would close this as duplicate, but I couldn't find a proper question, because SO's the search engine is so bad. I must assume that this question was never asked if it cannot be found.

Comment: @Andreas `Array.prototype.sort` modifies the input array which is not expected in a function that returns sorted array.

Comment: Took me less than five minutes to find the same dupe this question has been closed with now...: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+array+of+objects+sort+specific+value+first+then+rest+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: OP has not mentioned that the input array should not be modified

Comment: That's true, I'm just not a fan of procedures over functions

Comment: Then you should at least mention why you've added that extra step ;)

Answer (score -1):

[The reduce() method executes a user-supplied "reducer" callback function on each element of the array, in order, passing in the return value from the calculation on the preceding element. The final result of running the reducer across all elements of the array is a single value.][1]
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce